# How do you perform a "~" (bitwise NOT) on a OptionSetType

Tags: swift, set, swift2, bitmask

Up till Swift 1.2 you could perform a `~` (NOT) on a bitmask:

```
bitmask = ~otherBitmask
```

But in Swift 2.0 bitmasks are now `OptionSetType` and you can't use a `~` on a `OptionSetType`, how do you now do a `~` operation on a `OptionSetType`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the "bitwise NOT" on the raw value. Example:

```
let otherBitmask : NSCalendarOptions = [.MatchLast, .MatchNextTime]
let bitmask = NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: ~otherBitmask.rawValue)
```

If you need that frequently, you can define a generic
`~` operator for `OptionSetType`:

```
prefix func ~<T : OptionSetType where T.RawValue : BitwiseOperationsType>(rhs: T) -> T {
    return T(rawValue: ~rhs.rawValue)
}

let otherBitmask : NSCalendarOptions = [.MatchLast, .MatchNextTime]
let bitmask = ~otherBitmask
```

Comment: This _is_ the answer but to be fully correct I just wanted to note one thing: in my particular case the `OptionSetType` I was using (`CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask`) is a `Uint32`.  `CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue` is '31' and if you `~31` you get -32 but if you `~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue` you get 4294967264.  So, for completeness, you need to make sure you cast the `UInt32` to something like `Int`.

Comment: @Shizam: I don't think so. `let otherBitmask : CGBitmapInfo = [.AlphaInfoMask] ; let bitmask = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: ~otherBitmask.rawValue)` works just the same.